# Android BaseAdapter Pinterest style

Tags: android, android-layout, jquery-masonry, pinterest

What are some ways to make the vertical spacing between views the same, as shown in the picture below?

(**What I have**)
[image]

(**What I need**)
[image]

I've tried playing around with the height of the LinearLayout that I inflate for each of those "tiles", but can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: okay, so android-layout and jquery are not the same tech. android-layout refers to the XML elements in a native app and jquery would not be on a native app. So, what are you building?

Comment: As indicated from the screenshot of what I have, I'm building a native Android app. I realize that the answer I'm looking for will not involve a jQuery import... Since jQuery Masonry (plugin) achieves the same effect that I'm after, I'd assume that anyone who knows how Masonry achieves that Pinterest style would be able to help me.

Comment: yeah, so it wasn't obvious in the screen shot otherwise I wouldn't have asked you for clarification. Secondly, how a jquery plugin does it, in javascript, will not exactly port over to android in java. If you really want help i would suggest you post some code and maybe a short list of things you have tried.

Comment: one would think that words like base adapter, views and linear layout would make it obvious that no javascript was used in that app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check this library. It's in beta state:

[AntipodalWall](https://github.com/expilu/AntipodalWall)

[Web](http://expilu.github.io/AntipodalWall/)

Comment: scrolling is super slow on this library.

Answer (score 1):

We won’t be needing any external library for this as Android’s native RecyclerView makes implementing a Pinterest masonry layout simply by changing the RecyclerView’s Layout Manager

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Cool. it's Very easy ,but margin on my LinearLayout didn’t seem to work. So here’s a quick fix.

```
SpacesItemDecoration decoration = new SpacesItemDecoration(16);
mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(decoration);
```

SpacesItemDecoration class:

```
public class SpacesItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
private final int mSpace;

public SpacesItemDecoration(int space) {
    this.mSpace = space;
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    outRect.left = mSpace;
    outRect.right = mSpace;
    outRect.bottom = mSpace;

    // Add top margin only for the first item to avoid double space between items
    if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0)
        outRect.top = mSpace;
    }
}
```

[Github link of example](https://github.com/Suleiman19/Masonry)

[image: my final Results]